# Smallest set of integers such that their sums yield a given set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, summation

This is without any elements in this "smallest set" being used more than once in the sums. Otherwise $\{1\}$ would cover everything.

$\{1, 2, 3\}$ is the smallest set, the sums of the elements of which, generate the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$

I suspect that $\{1, ..., n\}$ would be the smallest set that generates $\{1, ..., \sum_{i=1}^n i\}$ but I don't know how to prove that. I can only prove that it generates it (with induction).

In general, I would like to find the smallest set $P'$ such that its sums can generate some set $P$

I'd also be interested in whether, if this requires some brute forcing in general, there would be some way to take the known generating sets for some sets ($P_1, ..., P_n$), ($P_1', ..., P_n'$) that are disjoint (or not) subsets of some set $Q = \cup_{i=1}^n P_i$ and use them to find $Q'$. (maybe a recursive function for a program, with some sufficient base cases)

Any analysis of this type of generating set would be helpful. The reverse, "how many elements are in the largest set $P$ that can be generated with the generating set $P'$," (since it would be less than or equal to the cardinality of the power set of $P'$), would also be helpful.

Comment: Note that $\{2^k:k=0,\ldots,n-1\}$ generates $\{1,\ldots,2^n-1\}$ and hence any subset thereof.

Comment: This is true. But there may be some sets strictly in between $\{1, ..., 2^n - 1\}$ and $\{1, ..., 2^{n - 1} - 1\}$ that can be generated by a smaller generating set.